# MongoDB Data Model - One document can link to multiple documents with different status

Tags: mongodb, database-design, data-modeling

I currently deal with a problem which is data structure with mongodb. I have two collections: services and users. The services will be in different status with each user, and admin is able to change status of the service for each user.

services collection:

```
[

    {

         _id: ObjectID(...),
         name: ...,
         status: [
             {
                 userId: ObjectID(...),
                 status: 0
             },
             {
                 userId: ObjectID(...),
                 status: 1
             },
             {
                 userId: ObjectID(...),
                 status: 4
             }
         ]
    }
]
```

user collection:

```
[

    {
         _id: ObjectID(...),
         name: ...,
         email: ...,
         phone: ....
    }
]
```

This structure is ok for small amount of data. However, let's imagine, we have 10,000 users and 1000 services, and each service has to include all users with their status. I believe it is not really good. Therefore, I am looking for some neat and nice solutions. Thank you for reading.

Comment: It is the kind of operations you perform on the data that matters, not the amount of data - this should be the factor in deciding the data model. So, tell what are the important operations (queries and updates) you will be performing on this data? You can also try embedding the services within the user collections (instead of users embedded in the services).

Comment: Thank you for responding. My functions mainly focus on services, so I decided to embed users in services. So, even if I have 10,000 users with their status  embedded in services collection, everything should be good, right?

Comment: Having embedded arrays is fine, as long as theses arrays are known/finite/constant in size and not growing. MongoDB has many methods and indexing to work with arrays.

Comment: It won't scale well if the number of users grows. MongoDB has a limit on the document size, which is 16MB, so you'll have to deal with it when the amount of users of service outgrows that. Also in this case any time you need to get a service document you will fetch all users which will increase the traffic. Or you would need to use aggregation pipeline and projections every time you query a service.

Comment: @prasad_ The problem is size will grow overtime because more users will sign up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there has to be a concept of service status for user, which can be stored in dedicated collection. It would have a user id, a service id and a status. In this case statuses can be managed independently from users or services and solution would be much more scalable. The collection would look something like:

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    userId: ObjectId(...),
    serviceId: ObjectId(...)
    status: 1
  }
]
```

If you would need some more data when querying services you could consider embedding that data into the user or service object inside the service status object (basically a de-normalization and redundancy), but it will require some efforts to keep that data in-sync with other collections:

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    user: {
      _id: ObjectId(...),
      name: ...
    },
    service: {
      _id: ObjectId(...),
      name: ...
    }
    status: 1
  }
]
```

Where `user` and `service` fields are "references" to data in users and services collections which are "source of truth" for the data.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for the suggestion. It looks similar to the concept of many-to-many from relational SQL. As you mentioned before, the limit of a document is about 16MB, so how's about  if the middle-man collections is over this limit?

Comment: Yup, that's basically what the concept is: many-to-many relationship between users and services. The limit of 16MB is per document, not per collection. Basically collection can grow as large as storage allows and if that's not enough it can be sharded across multiple replica sets, which is supported out of the box by MongoDB. So there is not such limit of 16MB with this approach.

Comment: Oh document limit not collection limit. My bad. Look like many-to-many is never outdated. Thank you for useful knowledge.